# Fatal error in custom sugar crm view

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have created a custom module (batch_Batches), with a custom view in sugarcrm 6.3.0.RC2. When navigating to `index.php?module=batch_Batches&action=myhello` I get the error:

> Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in
>   C:\sugar2\SugarCRM\include\utils.php on line 1038

These are the files I created for the custom view. What am I missing?

**modules\batch_Batches\views\view.myHello.php**:

```
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry)
die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/MVC/View/SugarView.php');

class myHello extends SugarView {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::SugarView();
    }


    public function display() {

        echo "ok";

    }
}
```

**modules\batch_Batches\action_view_map.php**:

```
$action_view_map['myHello']= 'myHello';
```

**modules\batch_Batches\controller.php**:

```
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class Batch_BatchesController extends SugarController {

    function action_myHello()
    {
        $this->view='myHello';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need either the map or the controller. I don't think you need both. That could be causing the looping.

Answer (score 4):

For non-custom Modules this happens when the name of the view Class is wrong.

For example if the module is Contacts then the view should be **ContactsViewmyHello**

Example:

```
class ContactsViewmyHello extends SugarView {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::SugarView();
    }


    public function display() {

        echo "ok";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

view.myHello.php filename should be lowercase:
modules\batch_Batches\views\view.myhello.php: